# 'Too many connections' error after redeploying webapp

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am using `AbstractRoutingDataSource` to create multitenancy in my application. I noticed that after a few redeployments of the webapp from my IDE I eventually get the MySQL error "Too many connections".
After further investigations, I found out that when I run the MySQL command `show processlist;`, I see that the open connection amount is increased by 10 after each deployment, which probably means that the connection pool is somehow still alive somewhere.
Before I used `AbstractRoutingDataSource` I used the default spring datasource configuration (using `application.properties`) and it worked fine.

Here's the Multitenant configuration class:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 * Created by Alon Segal on 16/03/2017.
 */
@Configuration
public class MultitenantConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private DataSourceProperties properties;

    /**
     * Defines the data source for the application
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(
            prefix = "spring.datasource"
    )
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        //Creating datasources map "resolvedDataSources" here

        MultitenantDataSource dataSource = new MultitenantDataSource();
        dataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(defaultDataSource());
        dataSource.setTargetDataSources(resolvedDataSources);

        // Call this to finalize the initialization of the data source.
        dataSource.afterPropertiesSet();

        return dataSource;
    }

    /**
     * Creates the default data source for the application
     *
     * @return
     */
    private DataSource defaultDataSource() {
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

And the datasource class:

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource;

/**
 * Created by Alon Segal on 16/03/2017.
 */
public class MultitenantDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return TenantContext.getCurrentTenant();
    }
}
```

I also tried to use `@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")` but there is not close method defined on `AbstractRoutingDataSource`.

I searched everywhere but could not find and answer. Can someone help me understand what's preventing the connection pool from being released between redeployments?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `resolvedDataSource` s should be closed. Apparently you aren't creating those as spring beans, meaning that they hang around instead of being closed. Either make those resolved datasources sprig beans so that spring can close it or implement a close method in your `MultitenantDataSource` which closes them.

Comment: Thanks @M.Denium for the answer. How can I create them as Spring beans? they're created dynamically based on configuration files..

Comment: Then it might be the easiest to create a `close` method in your `MultitenantDataSource` and close all the `targetDataSources` you wired into it.

Comment: why dont use pool ? like hikari or apache

Comment: @ali That did not solve my problem but it's useful anyway. I adopted the Hikari connection pool which apparently more powerful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I eventually solved the issue by giving up on using Spring's `AbstractRoutingDataSource` and instead using Hibernate's mechanism for multitenancy based on the solution that can be found in [this article](http://stuartingram.com/2016/10/02/spring-boot-schema-based-multi-tenancy/).

**Long story short**

You need to do 3 steps:

**Step 1**: Create a CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver

```
@Component
public class TenantIdentifierResolver implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {

    @Override
    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
        String tenantId = TenantContext.getCurrentTenant();
        if (tenantId != null) {
            return tenantId;
        }
        return DEFAULT_TENANT_ID;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Step 2**: Create a MultiTenantConnectionProvider

```
@Component
public class MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        connection.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifie) throws SQLException {
        String tenantIdentifier = TenantContext.getCurrentTenant();
        final Connection connection = getAnyConnection();
        try {
            if (tenantIdentifier != null) {
                connection.createStatement().execute("USE " + tenantIdentifier);
            } else {
                connection.createStatement().execute("USE " + DEFAULT_TENANT_ID);
            }
        }
        catch ( SQLException e ) {
            throw new HibernateException(
                    "Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema [" + tenantIdentifier + "]",
                    e
            );
        }
        return connection;
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try {
            connection.createStatement().execute( "USE " + DEFAULT_TENANT_ID );
        }
        catch ( SQLException e ) {
            throw new HibernateException(
                    "Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema [" + tenantIdentifier + "]",
                    e
            );
        }
        connection.close();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class unwrapType) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> unwrapType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Step 3**: Wire it up

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JpaProperties jpaProperties;

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,
                                                                       MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl,
                                                                       CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl) {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.putAll(jpaProperties.getHibernateProperties(dataSource));
        properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.SCHEMA);
        properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl);
        properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.autorni");
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        return em;
    }

}
```